# Need help to prove this function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f:R\to$ $R$ is continuous on $R$, and that $f(r)=0$ for every rational number r. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $R$.

I let r in $R-Q$, and $f(x)= lim(f(r_n))=f(lim(r_n))=lim(0)=0$. How can I write it in a more formal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, then you are done: $f(x)=0$ by assumption. Otherwise, let $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$ (which exists, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$).

You then have, by assumption:, that $f(r_n)=0$ for all $n$; but also by construction that $r_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} x$. Then,
$$
f(r_n) = 0 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
but, by continuity of $f$, 
$$
f(r_n) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} f(x).
$$
By unicity of the limit, $f(x)=0$.

---

Another proof: as $f$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is a closed set, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed. But $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\})$; that is, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed set contained $\mathbb{Q}$. The smallest closed set containing $\mathbb{Q}$ is the adherence of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $\mathbb{R}$ (as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). So $\mathbb{R} \subseteq f^{-1}(\{0\}) \ (\subseteq \mathbb{R})$, and you are done.